# Not authorized to assume the provided role

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am following the [AWS Step Functions tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-a-serverless-workflow-step-functions-lambda/).  The whole state machine process is like this.

[image]

I have a role called **step_functions_basic_execution** with policy `AWSLambdaRole`. My Step function state machine is using this role.

My step function is

```
{
  "Comment": "A simple AWS Step Functions state machine that automates a call center support session.",
  "StartAt": "Open Case",
  "States": {
    "Open Case": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:829495130000:function:OpenCaseFunction",
      "Next": "Assign Case"
    }, 
    ...
}
```

The corresponding **Open Case** Lambda function is

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // Create a support case using the input as the case ID, then return a confirmation message   
   var myCaseID = event.inputCaseID;
   var myMessage = "Case " + myCaseID + ": opened...";   
   var result = {Case: myCaseID, Message: myMessage};
   callback(null, result);    
};
```

When I tried to run it, it failed at first step **Open Case**.

The input is

```
{
  "inputCaseID": "001"
}
```

It throws error:

> States.TaskFailed
>
> Neither the global service principal states.amazonaws.com, nor the
>   regional one is authorized to assume the provided role.

Any idea how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks Joel Kinzel's guide. It was my mistake.

I did wrong at Step 2c.

> On the Create Roles screen, leave AWS Service selected, select Step
>   Functions

I chose **Lambda** instead of **Step Functions**, even next page is I still added `AWSLambdaRole`, but it does not help and cause the issue.

Answer (score 4):

the role need to have the following description:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

look the service name: is states.amazonaws.com not lambda.amazonaws.com

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053705/principal-states-amazonaws-com-is-not-authorized-to-assume-the-provided-role Can you please take a look here?

Answer (score 1):

Double check everything from Steps 2, 3, and 4 of that page. Unfortunately the error message isn't detailed enough for us to know exactly what is going on but it is something with the IAM set up.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly I feel. I followed the tutorial again and got same issue. The tutorial does not say clear which policies should be added for the IAM role. I was based on their screenshot. I tried to add one more policy `AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess` for the **step_functions_basic_execution** role, but still same. I will send their feedback and see if get any response and post back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two roles:
A)
IAM role for lambda (LambdaExecutionRole).This roles needs no policies and the following definition for Trust Relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

B) The second role (StatesExecutionRole) is for the StateMachine to be able to call the lambda functions. These roles need this policy definition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And needs this Trust relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "states.us-east-2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

The LambdaExecutionRole needs to be assigned to your lambdas.
The StatesExecutionRole needs to be assigned as the role to use to execute the StateMachine.

Comment: Can you please take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053705/principal-states-amazonaws-com-is-not-authorized-to-assume-the-provided-role

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post and already approved as resolved,
But maybe this will help someone...

I had a similar error but used another aws guide to create the roles:
https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-lambda-state-machine-cloudformation.html#lambda-state-machine-cfn-create-role

**The problem on my case was related to regions.**

I ran the StepFunction from **eu-west-1** region and got the same error as posted on the question:

```
States.TaskFailed

Neither the global service principal states.amazonaws.com, nor the regional 
one is authorized to assume the provided role.
```

Although my stepFunction role was configured exactly the same as described on the guide:

```
StatesExecutionRole:
 Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
 Properties:
   AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
     Version: "2012-10-17"
     Statement:
       - Effect: "Allow"
         Principal:
           Service:
             - !Sub states.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
         Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
   Path: "/"
   Policies:
     - PolicyName: StatesExecutionPolicy
       PolicyDocument:
         Version: "2012-10-17"
         Statement:
           - Effect: Allow
             Action:
               - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
             Resource: "*"
```

Once the role was created, I notice that the trusted entities for my role were:

```
"states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
```

[trusted entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DImF9.png)

So, that is why I could not ran the SFN from another region than us-east-1.
So if you are using the same guide pay attention to the trusted entities created from it.
I ended up changing the role into a general service configuration ("states.amazonaws.com") as the following:

```
StatesExecutionRole:
Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
Properties:
  AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
    Version: "2012-10-17"
    Statement:
      - Effect: "Allow"
        Principal:
          Service:
            - "states.amazonaws.com"
        Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
  Path: "/"
  Policies:
    - PolicyName: StatesExecutionPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
            Resource: "*"
```

And this solved the problem on my case.

Comment: Can you please take a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70053705/principal-states-amazonaws-com-is-not-authorized-to-assume-the-provided-role